# Importing Pictures With Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image, bluej

So, I recently switched from BlueJ to Eclipse (Its soooo much better!), and while moving over some of my java files, I realized that Eclipse doesnt support Pictures... In BlueJ, to import a picture file, you would just do:

```
Picture picVariable = new Picture("PictureFile.bmp");
```

But, for some reason I get syntax errors doing that in Eclipse... How would I load up a picture in Eclipse?

Also, to show a Picture in BlueJ, you would just do:

```
picVariable.show();
```

...How would you do that in Eclipse?
Thanks!

Comment: could you post the errors you are getting

Comment: Eclipse supports images just fine, but you have to know where *Java* is looking to find the pictures. It's likely not where you think. Try putting `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` in your code to see the spot.

Comment: also, what is the full class name of the picture class you are using? If that question doesn't make sense can you show the import statements you have in your .java file?

Comment: When I type in the declaring statement I have above, eclipse puts red lines below both "Picture" Words. when I hover above it, it says it cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: And I dont have any imports for picture, as I have never needed any when I was using BlueJ

Comment: Ditto to everything Eric has said above. Once we get all this straight, then we can move on to showing you how to get images and similar items as resources, not as files. ;)

Comment: What is the Picture class though? It's not part of standard Java.

Comment: Hovercraft, I know where Java looks to find the picture file. Its right in the Main project file. But just to make sure, I just added the full path name in the declaration and it didnt make any difference.

Comment: Im not sure what class it is, but it always worked in BlueJ and I never had to import anything.

Comment: @Chris: Perhaps you had a Picture class in your current package in BlueJ but don't have one in Eclipse. Again, the Picture class is not a part core Java library.

Comment: I'd invite you to discuss this in chat, but I think that you need to have more rep points for you to do this. Sorry.

Comment: Just googled and found this... http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/Picture.html

Comment: Which is the class I've been using for the past 5 months. Do you think it's built into BlueJ? Because I dont have any Libraries configured in BlueJ.

Comment: ahhh nevermind, I've solved it. Aparently bluej has been refrencing a library, and within it was the picture class. so all i had to do was add that library to Eclipse and now it works :) Thanks for all the help!

Comment: well if you can find the source code for that class, or the .class file in your BlueJ install then you can add it to your Eclipse projects

Comment: Good job! Look forward to seeing you "around" these parts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with BlueJ but the fact that you don't need to do any imports tells me that 'Picture' is some BlueJ specific class.

When Eclipse says its can't resolve the type that means it can't find a definition for the class 'Picture' on your class path.

In normal Java its pretty easy to display a picture.

See the following mailing list thread for a very simple way:

http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/527-simplest-way-read-display-jpeg-image.html

The basic premise is you create an ImageIcon, then use a JLabel to render it (assuming you are using a SwingGui.

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("filename");
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
```

Comment: and presuming the image file is in the user.dir. 1+

Answer (score 0):

I found what is apparently the library you need.

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/stdlib.jar

Download that jar file, drop it on your project folder in the Eclipse project directory. Right click on the jar and select 'Add to Build Path'